# db2: how to set the timing and show rows modified?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

On Postgres i use set timing

```
\timing
```

and show me timing and how much rows updated

```
update sales set target = 20000;
UPDATE 5
Time: 638,375 ms
```

on db2 is a little silent

```
db2 => update sales set target = 20000;
DB20000I The SQL command completed successfully.
```

How to show timing and rows updated on db2?
Is the standard local client called db2.

Edit: I have solved for the "verbose" mode

```
db2 -m
```

or

```
export DB2OPTIONS="-m"
db2
```

But I found nothing for timing, except a workaround using batch mode and unix time command(sic!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Db2 has a dedicated benchmark tool named [db2batch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002043.html). It can even print out more than just the timings and give you details about how many rows were impacted / fetched.